# Identifying where a message was forwarded to

Tags: email, exim

This is one of those hard to explain questions. I've tried my best below, hopefully it is clear what I mean.

Emails are coming in to an address (**foo@example.com**), and are being forwarded to another email address (**bar@subdomain.example.com**). The second email address further pipes the email to a simple script, but the script needs to actually know the second email address as it provides meta-data that is crucial to sorting the message (that is, the script gets piped any email sent to *@subdomain.example.com, and it needs to see that it got forwarded to **bar@subdomain.example.com** in order to correctly process the incoming message).

Originally, I thought that the virtual alias used to forward messages from **foo@example.com** to **bar@subdomain.example.com** would update the envelope-to header, but it remains unchanged the same. None of the other headers nor the "received" line reflect that the message was forwarded. My theory is that maybe the pipe instructions for ***@subdomain.example.com** can be updated to somehow pass the actual address on to the script, but I am not sure how.

For reference, I have included a few examples below:

Headers, after being forwarded:

```
From sender@example.com Sun Dec 11 19:53:40 2011
Envelope-to: foo@example.com
Received: ...
Subject: Test 6
```

The valias file for subdomain.example.com (/etc/valiases/subdomain.example.com):

```
*: "|/home/user/example_script.x.php"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I answered my own question. It turns out, the recipient is accessible in an environment variable. In my case, since I am using PHP, I can just use the following variable:

```
$_ENV['RECIPIENT']
```